# Extra chars being sent from webserver C/C++

Tags: c, http, webserver

I am creating a simple webserver to send documents to a browser, but for some of the documents extra characters are being sent. The initial HTML is okay, but the proceeding javascript and css has additional characters at the end that make it seem like a buffer overflow. I am using about 2048 bytes in the stack, which I think is okay. Here is the code for sending documents (the document is already opened and checked that it opened correctly)

```
    // make header
    char header[MaxSize + 50];
 
    if (other[0] == 0) {
      sprintf(header, "%s 200 %s follows \r\nServer: %s\r\nContent-type: %s\r\n\r\n", httpVer, docuReq, serverType, docT);
    } else {
      sprintf(header, "%s 200 %s follows \r\nServer: %s\r\nContent-type: %s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", httpVer, docuReq, serverType, docT, other);
    }
 
    send(fd, header, strlen(header), 0);

    // send document
    fseek(document, 0, SEEK_END);
    int bytes = ftell(document);
    fseek(document, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char * buff = (char*)malloc(bytes + 1);
 
    fread(buff, bytes, 1, document);
 
    send(fd, buff, bytes, 0);
    free(buff);
 
    fclose(document);
 
    char closing[5];
    sprintf(closing, "\r\n\r\n");
    closing[4] = 0;
    send(fd, closing, strlen(closing), 0);
```

Update:
The document was open in read-only, so I changed the following code

```
fread(buff, bytes, 1, document);
```

to

```
    int readBytes = fread(buff, 1, bytes, document);
    send(fd, buff, readBytes, 0);
```

which fixed the problem of the .js and .css files being sent incorrectly. Unfortunately images/gifs are still not working. I checked the difference between readBytes and bytes, and readBytes is drastically lower than bytes for images/gifs. I know that means fread failed mid-read, but I am unsure why it would fail.

Comment: You ***must*** check for errors from all functions you call. They can all fail when you least expect it.

Comment: It's also going to be very hard to say anything specific without a proper [mcve]. The problem might not even be in the code you show.

Comment: What values do you pass to `sprintf`? What is their maximum string length? What is the value of `MaxSize`? I suggest to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to avoid possible buffer overflow and to check the return value to find out if truncation occurred. Please [edit] your question and show an example of the additional characters.

Comment: The `(char*)` cast of the `malloc` return value makes me think that you are using a C++ compiler to compile this C code. Why not use a C++ class, like `std::string buf(bytes + 1, '\0');` or `std::vector<char> buf(bytes + 1);` and provide `buf.data()` to `fread()`?

Comment: It is not an error, but instead of using `sprintf` to fill a constant string into a fixed size array `char closing[5]` I suggest to use initialization like `const char closing[] = "\r\n\r\n";` or a pointer to a string literal `const char *closing = "\r\n\r\n";`

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess that you `fopen` the file in plain read mode - not read+binary mode. If I'm wrong, then you can probably disregard this answer. :)

If I'm right however, then I guess that you get as many garbage characters at the end of your file as there are lines in it. What happens is that `fread` reads `\r\n` (which is the line break format in Windows), and converts it to only `\n` (which is the default format most other places). This means that for every time it reads two `\r\n` bytes, it only puts one `\n` byte into your buffer, which means that the last "number of lines" bytes of your buffer just isn't filled with data.

If you open your file in read+binary mode then this conversion does not happen, and you get exactly the number of bytes in your buffer that you expect.

EDIT:

Like @AlanBirtles commented, you can also change:

```
fread(buff, bytes, 1, document);
send(fd, buff, bytes, 0);
```

to:

```
int readBytes = fread(buff, 1, bytes, document);
send(fd, buff, readBytes, 0);
```

Note though that I changed the `fread` call so that instead of reading 1 item of size `bytes`, it now tries to read `bytes` number of items of size 1. This is because [fread man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html):

> On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1.

Comment: You could also check the return value of fread to get the actual number of bytes read and only send that many bytes

Comment: @AlanBirtles True, I should have remembered that.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was exactly the problem you were saying.